# How do I force pandoc to find my css file when converting mkd to html?

Tags: html, css, markdown, pandoc

I'm using pandoc to convert a mkd file to html, and the style options I require are stored in a css file, which I keep in the same folder as the mkd file (which is also the working directory). However, pandoc seems not to see my css file. There is no error message, but the information in the css file is ignored.

I created a minimal example as follows.

hello.mkd contains the following:

```
# Hello

world
```

hello.css contains the following:

```
h1 { font-family: "Courier"; }
```

and then I run:

```
pandoc hello.mkd -f markdown -t html -c hello.css -o hello.html
```

This creates the hello.html file, but the Hello heading is not in Courier.

I'm using a Mac and pandoc version 2.7.3, in case this is relevant.

Many thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: what pandoc version are you on? you can also try adding the `--self-contained` option..

Comment: pandoc version 2.7.3.

Comment: I tried adding --self-contained. This didn't immediately work, because I got the error message: ```This document format requires a nonempty <title> element.
  Please specify either 'title' or 'pagetitle' in the metadata,
  e.g. by using --metadata pagetitle="..." on the command line.``` but upon adding ``--metadata pagetitle="test"``, it worked. Thank you!